# How to enable Drag and Copy cell function same as excel, where + sign appears in right corner of cell, in c1 flexgrid in WPF?

Tags: wpf, c1flexgrid

I need Ctrl+D functionality of excel in my C1FlexGrid in WPF.
Also I need to implement Drag n Copy function of Excel cell in C1FlexGrid.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about this working with C1flexgrid but can be worth a try.
Check "Require Elevated permissions" in silverlight project properties and using drop event of silverlight datagrid one can handle the drag and drop from desktop in a silverlight datagrid provided its not an OOB silverlight application.

```
private void DocumentsDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
 e.Handled = true;

var point = e.GetPosition(null);
var dataGridRow = ExtractDataGridRow(point);
if(dataGridRow !=null)
{.....
}

var droppedItems = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop) as      FileInfo[];
if (droppedItems != null)
 {
    var droppedDocumentsList = new List<FileInfo>();

    foreach (var droppedItem in droppedItems)
    {
        if ((droppedItem.Attributes & FileAttributes.Directory) == FileAttributes.Directory)
        {
            var directory = new DirectoryInfo(droppedItem.FullName);
            droppedDocumentsList.AddRange(directory.EnumerateFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
        }
        else
        {
            droppedDocumentsList.Add(droppedItem);
        }
    }

    if (droppedDocumentsList.Any())
    {
        ProcessFiles(droppedDocumentsList);
    }
    else
    {
        DisplayErrorMessage("The selected folder is empty.");
    }
}
}
```

Set AllowDrop =true; in xaml for the datagrid. From the DragEventArgs extract the information as FileInfo Object.